# Which database can be used with .Net instead of MS SQL Server, with same functionalities but open-source?

Tags: open-source, database, .net, asp.net

I want develop a new web application in .net, but for database I want don't want MySQL, but same powerful database needed, Which one is best like MySQL or BigData open source database?

Comment: “Which is best” is not an appropriate Question here. Here you supply a list of criteria, and we supply suggestions for products that meet those particular needs.

Answer (score 1):

## Postgres

[image]

The world’s most advanced open-source relational database is [*Postgres*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL).

Quite full-featured, one of the databases most compliant with the SQL standard. Famed for its reliability and faithfulness in not losing your data. Enterprise-levels of quality and performance. Perhaps the best documentation in the industry. Its `json-b` data type outperforms the NoSQL databases in some regards for JSON storage and retrieval.

Free-of-cost. Active mailing lists, and many conferences around the world. Increasingly available as a cloud service from Heroku, Amazon Web Services, Microsoft Azure, and others.

Less famous than MySQL, but far better in engineering and reliability.

Runs on many platforms, including Windows.

Has many drivers available for many programming languages. [Here](https://www.npgsql.org/) is one driver for .Net. You might find others as well.

Note that many of Microsoft’s tools work only with MS SQL Server. So you may need to find replacements for those, depending on your needs.